# Spark Structured Streaming Protobuf ScalaPB 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, protocol-buffers

I am new to use Spark Structured Streaming 2.2.2 to decode protobuf messages.
I used ScalaPB standalone to generate the scala code from my .proto file. Now I want to parse from Kafaka messages.
This is my code.

```
import scalapb.spark.Implicits._
val pbDs = kafkaDs
      .map(row => row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("value"))
      .map(Person.parseFrom(_).entries.head)
```

and build.sbt. I add scalapb-runtime as dependancy because Person is generated by ScalaPB standalone compiler.(refer to https://scalapb.github.io/scalapbc.html)

```
lazy val myDep = Seq(
    "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "sparksql-scalapb" % "0.9.0",
    "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % "0.9.0")
```

But scalaPB gave error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.objects.StaticInvoke$.apply$default$6()Z
    at frameless.TypedEncoder$$anon$1.toCatalyst(TypedEncoder.scala:51)
    at frameless.TypedExpressionEncoder$.apply(TypedExpressionEncoder.scala:29)
    at scalapb.spark.Implicits$class.typedEncoderToEncoder(TypedEncoders.scala:125)
    at scalapb.spark.Implicits$.typedEncoderToEncoder(TypedEncoders.scala:128)
```

I googled the error and say it's becos frameless is complied against Java 6. Is that true? How does everyone else do this?